# JQuery No Table Sorting Plugin Works(TypeError: ... not a function)

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, jquery-plugins, html-table

I have tried both the stupid-table and tablesorter jquery plugins, but neither works! I keep getting the error: "TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function" (the same error with stupidtable). In firefox I can see the js file with the debugger, so I know it's being loaded.

Does anyone have an idea?

My code(HTML):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tablesort/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tablesort/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../util/js/search.js"></script>
...
<table id='category-results' class='search-results'>
            <caption>Category Results</caption>
            <colgroup id="category-columns">
                <col id="category-names"/>
                <col id="category-parents"/>
                <col id="category-problems"/>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category Name</th>
                    <th>In Category</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Math</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>
                    <td>Algebraic Geometry</td>
                    <td>Math</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell Biology</td>
                    <td>Biology</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>           
            </tbody>                
        </table>
```

And Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#category-results").tablesorter(); 
$("#category-results").delegate('th','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {            
        $("#category-results col").eq( $(this).index()).addClass("column-hover");
    }else{
        $("#category-results col").eq( $(this).index()).removeClass("column-hover");            
    }
});
});
```

I have tried everything I could think of, putting it in the html document as a jquery script, using the google jquery version, changing the directory structure... The thing that I don't understand is that the examples work in my browser for both plugins, so it has to be something on my end. I have some php code for database stuff, but that shouldn't effect this.

Thanks!

Comment: what errors do you get on the console?

Comment: That error typically means you are not including the plugin, are including two copies of jquery, or are including the plugin before jquery. Figure out which and you'll have your solution.

Comment: "TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function" is the only console error (in firefox console)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I imported JQuery twice, once in my header and once in the HTML. Thank you Kevin B!